# node can not find module - Backbone?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, requirejs, digital-ocean

having issue with loading Backbone dep fro my nodejs project:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'Backbone'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

When I navigate to node_modules I can see backbone directory with backbone.js file. It works locally but when I upload it to digitalocean and install deps with ssh it says that it throws error.

Please help

P.S. what I tried:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

still no luck

Comment: Why would you need Backbone from within Node?

Comment: Why wouldn't I? It's a great library to manage models and collections within node env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows is case-insensitive, Linux isn't. Try `require('backbone')` instead of `require('Backbone')`.

Comment: Well it seems that Mac OS X is also insensitive about these things and thats pretty strange :( Thanks, that solved an issue. I will accept your answer when I'm allowed